# How do I change the top-app-bar fill color in Google's Material Design?

Tags: html, sass, material-design

I am using Google's Material Design as a good UI design tool to help me create a web app for personal programming experience. I want to know how I can change the Top App Bar color with Sass. I can't figure out the documentation.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/

Basically, I want to change it to a hex color of anything. Here is my current code:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.scss" type="text/scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--short blue-bar">
            <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
                <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
                    <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">menu</a>
                    <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Title</span>
                </section>
                <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
                    <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item">settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item">account_circle</a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </header>
        <p>
            Nothing to see here.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### SCSS FILE

```
$base-color: #AD141E;
.blue-bar { @include mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color($base-color); }
```

I named the class `.blue-bar` just cause I felt like blue. It doesn't have to be blue. I just want to know how to change the default purple color of the bar.

## EDIT:

I just realized that you have to actually convert the scss file to css before you can use it. My **new** question is: Since I am using Google's Material Design CSS, how do I use Sass to edit that and change the color?

Comment: Post the working version of your code in question on Stackblitz so that people can see the problem clearly and act on it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your $base-color is actually a red color. Use `.blue-bar { @include mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color(#0000ff); }` or any other blue color instead

---

For information about compiling scss to css read the [Quick start guide](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/).
This makes using the unpkg unnecessary.
Basically you want to set up webpack to bundle your scss files to a single css file. Note that in webpack.config.js you have 2 output paths.

```
module.exports = [{
  entry: './app.scss',
  output: {
    // This is necessary for webpack to compile
    // But we never use style-bundle.js
    filename: 'style-bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              //This is where you specify the output for your bundled css file.
              //outputPath specifies where the file is stored (i'm doing this from my head so unsure about pathing)
              //Name is the filename.
              outputPath: './css'
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Change MDC top-app-bar fill-color

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar"; // namespace top-app-bar contains fill-color mixin
@use "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar"; // contains CSS classes

.mdc-top-app-bar {
  // fill-color($color) is defined in the top-app-bar namespace
  @include top-app-bar.fill-color(#29E);
}
```

## Compile MDC for web

For those who are not building a nodejs app or using a packer...

Get **@material** source, for example :

- Install npm
- Install mdc : npm i material-components-web
- Work with your copy of  node_modules/@material

Use **dart-sass** to compile your SCSS to CSS :

- Install sass binary from https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/
- Complile your code : sass -s compressed -I ../node_modules/ input.scss bundle.css

Use **esbuild** to compile your javascript code :

- Install the binary ( *Other installation methods (click to expand)*): https://github.com/evanw/esbuild
- Compile JS : esbuild --bundle --minify input.js --outfile=bundle.js

Unfortunately esbuild doesn't provide a path parameter and the node_modules directory must be available in your js files parent directory.